# How to use ASC and DESC in latest() in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$thread = Thread::with(['messages' => function($q) {
                    $q->with('detail_per_user');
                    $q->with('post');
                    $q->with(['forum' => function($sq) {
                            $sq->with(['forum_messages' => function($isq) {
                                    $isq->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
                                }]);
                        }]);
                    $q->with('attachments');
                    $q->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
                    $q->latest();
                    $q->take(20);
                }])->with('users.user_details:id,avtar,name,parent_id,generated_id')->where('id', '=', $thread_id)->get()->toArray();
```

> ASc and DSC not working in latest. i need to get latest 20 message in ASC order. result is coming in desc order.

Comment: Use `oldest()` instead of `latest()`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel `latest()`, `orderByDesc('created_at')` and `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` are equivalent and they will fetch data in `descending` order.

> `latest()` default column is `created_at` and default direction is `descending`

---

```
$thread = Thread::with(['messages' => function($q) {
    $q->with('detail_per_user');
    $q->with('post');
    $q->with(['forum' => function($sq) {
        $sq->with(['forum_messages' => function($isq) {
            $isq->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
        }]);
    }]);
    $q->with('attachments');
    $q->latest('id');
    $q->take(20);
}])->with('users.user_details:id,avtar,name,parent_id,generated_id')->where('id', '=', $thread_id)->get()->sortBy('id')->toArray();
```

First we sort the `messages` by `id` in `descending` order then we take 20 records then we sort the `collection` by `id` in `ascending` order.

You might need to add `->values()` after `sortBy('id')` as the record key will be reordered.